# Is there a way to play a video with ffplay by clicking on the video icon?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

For some reason all the movies I work with cannot be played with the ubuntu Video application or VLC. Right now the only way to play them is using the excellent player `ffplay` from the console.

My question is, is there a way that I can run ffplay with a click on the Files window?